# Powershell Separating a string into an array and iterating through

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I'm trying to separate a string in the following format,

```
STANDARDWOFFPACK_FACULTY ; FLOW_FREE
```

So that each entry in the string is an item within an array I can iterate through to do a function against. Any suggestions on how I would achieve this array would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split()` method:

```
$myString= 'STANDARDWOFFPACK_FACULTY ; FLOW_FREE'

$myString.split(';')
```

Which gives:

```
STANDARDWOFFPACK_FACULTY 
 FLOW_FREE
```

Note that this includes the extra spaces as part of the separate strings.  If you want rid of those, do this:

`$myString.split(';').Trim()`

To get the output in an array, simply capture it in a variable:

`$myArray = $myString.split(';').Trim()`

You can confirm it is an array with the `GetType()` method:

```
$myArray.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType    
-------- -------- ----     --------    
True     True     Object[] System.Array
```